# IIS web deploy problems

Tags: .net, iis, web-deployment

Yo

I have web deploy set up on server 1 which works - but i can't for the life of me remember how many goats and sheep i slaughtered to the MS gods of FUD to make it work.

Now i'm moving hosting over to an Amazon instance - i need to re-set up IIS.

Now - all i have done so far is install MS Web Deploy 2.0 through IIS.

I can't connect to anything and i dont have anything in the default site (i was expecting to see an MSDeploy2 or something - after a friend at work said i should - however - looking at the old server - i don't see anything there either)

what am i doing wrong? there are a million and one ways described on the internet of doing this and not one of them works because microsoft swap, change and rename everything every time someone at redmond farts.

Comment: What version of ASP.NET are you using? What version is installed on the server? What version of IIS do you have on the server? If the OS is Windows 2008 then it is IIS 7.

Comment: Do you have remote desktop access to the server?

Comment: IIS 7 - Windows server 2008 datacentre edition .NET 4. the app is installed and running. i just can't deploy to it using the publish feature in VS 2010 :(

Comment: Can anyone log in to the below link and answer to my question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29765796/webdeploy-is-able-to-promote-settings-for-particular-user-id%C2%B4s

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The complete reference guide to configure instance and deploy application](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/823/amazon-ec2-microsoft-web-platform-images---full-web-server-development-stack/)

Maybe you could try to install [Web Deploy](http://www.iis.net/download/WebDeploy) extension to IIS and try again? Check [manual to configure Web Deployment handler](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/516/configure-the-web-deployment-handler/)

Comment: that is EXCELLENT - but also a massive bummer as it means i need to start over!! thanks dude :)

Comment: only available on the US west coast - will this mean the site will suffer lag in the UK?

Comment: There are instances in Ireland (the article is almost year old, things changed), check the pricing section: http://aws.amazon.com/windows/

Comment: yeah but they aren't the community web-deploy images that were created?

Comment: Seems to be true, I wasn't able to find Web platform instances in EU catalog. Check update

Comment: yeah - unfortunately - that is what i have been doing :(

Comment: Another solution using FTP: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/431443/how-to-deploy-web-app-directly-from-visual-studio-2008

Comment: it just started working. no word of a lie - out of the blue - just before i was about to start crying, just after i begged and pleaded and made it a cup of tea.